# Минимальное положительное и максимальное отрицательное

Tags: c

Дан массив A из N целых чисел. Найти и вывести минимальное положительное и
максимальное отрицательное числа в этом массиве.
Input
В первой строке вводится целое число N (1<=N<=1000) — количество чисел в массиве
A. Во второй строке вводятся N целых положительных чисел — элементы массива A
(-10000<=Ai<=10000).
Output
Требуется вывести через пробел минимальное положительное и максимальное
отрицательное числа в этом массиве. Выводить пробел в конце не нужно.
Sample Input
7
1 2 -3 4 -5 0 6
Sample Output
1 -3

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
int i,n,a[20000],x,y; 
scanf("%d", &n); 
for (i=0; i<n; i++) 
scanf("%d", &a[i]); 
x=a[0];y=a[0];
for (i=0; i<n; i++) 
{
    if(x>a[i]&& a[i]>0) x=a[i];
    
}
 
for (i=0; i<n; i++) 
{
    if(y==a[i]) y=a[i];
    
}
for (i=0; i<n; i++) 
{
    if(y>a[i]) y=a[i];
    
}
for (i=0; i<n; i++) 
{
    if(y<a[i]&&a[i]<0) y=a[i];
    
}
printf("%d %d",x,y);
return 0; 
}
```

В чем может быть проблема, если код не работает только на 50%?

Comment: Вы всегда так код пишете? Читать удобно?

Comment: `if(y=a[i])` - вас не смущает присваивание внутри условия?

Comment: @andreymal, моя ошибка, прошу не судить строго, я новичок в программировании. Там должно быть ==

Answer (score 0):

если "на пальцах":

int plus,minus;

// элементы массива A (-10000<=Ai<=10000)

```
plus  = 10000;  // ищем минимальное положительное
minus = -10000; // ищем минимальное отрицательное

for i:= 0 to n-1 do
  begin
    if a[i] > 0
      then if a[i] < plus  then plus:= a[i]
                           else 
      else if a[i] > minus then minus:= a[i]
  end;
```

извините за мой Дельфийский, но смысл думается понятен ...

Comment: Получается, что дальше просто выводить plus и minus?